# Is it possible to re-arrange the indicators in the panel?

Tags: settings, wingpanel, desktop

Is there a way to customize my *taskbar*?

I don't want to see the date, I want to have the clock on the right side, instead of the middle, etc ... Mostly reorganizing, adding and removing stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to re-arrange the indicators in the panel.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible natively, but have a look at super wingpanel. https://heathpaddock.com/2013/12/14/super-wingpanel/

Comment: This will almost surely not work on recent versions of elementary OS